# Texting with Samsung Galaxy S4

Tags: sms, samsung-galaxy-s-4

My Samsung Galaxy S4 has been saying that my text is "sending" for hours now.  However, one of the recipients has responded to my text. Was not doing this earlier today

Answer (score 1):

"Have you tried turning it off and back on again?" Honestly, I would just recommend restarting your device. It might just magically fix the problem.

Sometimes, if you're sending a message to multiple recipients, one person will receive the message before the others. Your phone could have lost cellular service during the process of sending the message (thus resulting in one person replying while your message is still being sent to the others).

If restarting the phone doesn't work, you can try the dumb brute force solution:

1. Copy the content of the message.
2. Delete the message from your outbox.
3. Create a new message with the pasted content and send it.

Maybe another user can recommend a techy solution, but this should be enough to get you past this issue if it happens again. If it happens regularly, you should contact your carrier.

Comment: "Is it plugged in?"

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely a carrier issue instead of a phone one.

Comment: Why do you think it's a carrier issue? Any reasons or sources for this?

Comment: When I had similar problems with my Galaxy S3, it was due to Sprint upgrading the towers where I was at. Now that the upgrades are complete, I've had no problems sending messages.